# I want to mint an NFT from another cosmwasm smart contract

Tags: archway-network, cosmwasm

I tried this code:

```rust
let metadata = Metadata {
            image: None,
            image_data: None,
            external_url: None,
            description: None,
            name: None,
            attributes: None,
            background_color: None,
            animation_url: None,
            youtube_url: None,
        };
        let mint_msg = MintMsg {
            token_id: ""123"".to_string(),
            owner: info.sender.to_string(),
            token_uri: None,
            extension: metadata.clone(),
        };
        let exec_msg = ExecuteMsg::Mint(mint_msg.clone());

        let res = wasm_execute(
            state.nft_address.ok_or(ContractError::EmptyNftMinter {})?,
            &exec_msg,
            vec![],
        )?;
```

It does not work, even though it compiles successfully. I feel that I miss small thing but i do not know what exactly. By the way, that nft contract was created from examples.

Additionally how can I call queries or entrypoints from a different contract.

Answer (score 1):

It is advised that interactions with other contracts, which will return data, should be handled in a sub-message rather than executing the action directly. This allows for deferred execution. When a contract creates a sub-message, it doesn't get executed immediately; instead, it is processed after the current contract's execution completes successfully.

Your solution could look like the following:

```rust
    let metadata = Metadata {
        image: None,
        image_data: None,
        external_url: None,
        description: None,
        name: None,
        attributes: None,
        background_color: None,
        animation_url: None,
        youtube_url: None,
    };
    let mint_msg = MintMsg {
        token_id: token_id,
        owner: info.sender.to_string(),
        token_uri: None,
        extension: metadata.clone(),
    };
    let exec_msg = ExecuteMsg::Mint(mint_msg.clone());
    
    let message = SubMsg::new(WasmMsg::Execute {
        contract_addr: state.nft_address.ok_or(ContractError::EmptyNftMinter {})?.to_string(),
        msg: to_binary(&exec_msg)?,
        funds: vec![],
    });
```